# Check Proof of total orders are maximal orders

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

**Recall:** A set $X$ together with a binary relation $\leq$ such that for all $x,y,z\in X$,

O$1$. $x\leq x$

$O2$. $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ then $x=y$

$O3$. $x\leq y$ and $y\leq z$ then $x\leq z$

is called an ordered or sometimes a partially ordered.

- An ordered $(X,\leq)$ is called a **total order** if for all $x,y\in X$, either $x\leq y$ or $y\leq x$.

**Theorem 1. Show that total orders are max orders.**

Let $\leq$ be a total order on $X$. There is no partial order on $X$ which extends $\leq$ because $\leq$ is total order.

**Theorem 2. Show that maximal order is total order.**

Let $\leq$ be an partial order on $X$ which is maximal. Since $\leq$ is maximal, any two elements of $X$ can be compatible via $\leq$, hence $\leq$ is total order.

**May you check my proofs? Can you give me alternative proof?** Thanks...

Comment: Your proofs are too brief, and don't seem to contain much logic. To show a partial order $\le$ is maximal, start by assuming there's a partial order $\preceq$ such that $a \le b \implies a \preceq b$. If $\le$ is total, you should be able to show the converse too. So, suppose $a \preceq b$. What does the totality of $\le$ show?

Comment: I agree with @TheoBendit.  You really need a lot more exposition.  I can't see how your proof applies to concrete examples.  For example, consider the partial order on $\Bbb C$ defined by $z_1 \leq z_2 \iff \operatorname{Im} (z_1) = \operatorname{Im} (z_2) \land \operatorname{Re} (z_1) \leq \operatorname{Re} (z_2).$  How does your proof apply to that partial order?

Comment: Thanks for comments

Comment: A "poset" (partially ordered set) has more than one  definition, depending on the context or the author. For  example in the set-theoretic topic of Forcing, $O2$ is omitted, and a poset satisfying $O2$ is called "strict".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet.  Those are called preorders.  The minority forcers are creating a language of there own,

Comment: There's an edit button for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Let S be a linear order.  Assume a <= b is not in the order of   S.
Define S' with the order including the order of S and a <= b.
As S is linear, b <= a is in S.
Thus within S', a <= b and b <= a;  a = b.
As a <= a is in the order of S and a = b, a <= b is is in the order of S.
That contradiction shows the impossibility of extending the order of S.

Let S be maximally ordered.
Assume some a,b with not a <= b and not b <= a.
Show that the order of S can be extended to include a <= b.
As S is maximally ordered, that is a contradiction.
Thus the negation of the assumption:  a <= b or b <= a.